# can order by follow it union select?

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible in an SQL query to add `UNION` after `order by 1`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE etc='1' ORDER BY 11;
```

can we add a union select query beside 11 to be like this ?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE etc='1' ORDER BY 11 UNION select etc etc etc ...;
```

Comment: -1 There are so many duplicate questions for this issue that I can't find the one I added meaningful comments to!

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can enclose the order by clause within a subquery and union the results of multiple subqueries; something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE etc='1' ORDER BY 11) sq1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE etc='2' ORDER BY 12) sq2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    11 AS orderby 
FROM 
    table1 
WHERE 
    etc='1' 
UNION 
select
    *,
    10 AS orderby 
FROM
    table2
ORDER BY
    orderby
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE etc='1' 
union 
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE etc='1' 
ORDER BY any_column
```

Comment: i know, but wondering if it was possible to use union after order by

Comment: It will behave in same manner you can use i this way and your job will be done. Try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `ORDER BY` at the end of the query after the last `union`. Basically all `SELECT`s are done first, then the entire result set is ordered.